# Cloud Foundry getting ERROR: Unknown CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request ERROR: Cloud Foundry error code: -1

Tags: jenkins

Pushing spring-music app to https://api.run.pivotal.io
Creating new app.

```
ERROR: Unknown CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request
ERROR: Cloud Foundry error code: -1
ERROR: The host is taken: spring-music
org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request (The host is taken: spring-music)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerResponseErrorHandler.getException(CloudControllerResponseErrorHandler.java:69)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerResponseErrorHandler.handleError(CloudControllerResponseErrorHandler.java:24)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:589)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:547)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.LoggingRestTemplate.doExecute(LoggingRestTemplate.java:54)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:503)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:331)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.doAddRoute(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1367)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.bindRoute(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1321)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.addUris(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1244)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.createApplication(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1187)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.createApplication(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1161)
    at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.createApplication(CloudFoundryClient.java:247)
    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushPublisher.createApplicationIfNeeded(CloudFoundryPushPublisher.java:386)
    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushPublisher.processOneApp(CloudFoundryPushPublisher.java:248)
    at com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushPublisher.perform(CloudFoundryPushPublisher.java:188)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Push to Cloud Foundry' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because the hostname spring-music might have been taken by someone else. So please specify a different application name and host name which might solve your problem